# the banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

let $A$ be a Banach algebra with identity,$\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, is it right?

$\sigma(a + \lambda 1 ) = \sigma(a) +\lambda$$\qquad$$(a \in A)$

> $\sigma (a) = \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} : \lambda 1 - a \qquad \text{is not invertible}  \} $$\qquad$$(a \in A)$

Comment: Where do you have problems with the proof?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Let $a' := a + \lambda 1$. Then 
$$ \sigma(a+\lambda 1) = \sigma(a') = \{\mu \in \mathbf C: \mu 1 - a' \text{ is not invertible}\} $$
Now use 
$$ \mu 1 - a' = \mu 1 - (a + \lambda 1) = (\mu - \lambda)1 - a $$